# Why am I not getting a password reset email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

In the first 8 minutes of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdK9dQ5Aok0), the developer tells you to uncomment the code in the `forgotpassword()` in the account controller, the email confirmation in the if, and finally the link to get the forgot password page on the login screen. He then tells you to write in the following code in your Identity config.

```
using System.Net.Mail;    
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    //Emails will be sent from this address
    var from = "someusername@gmail.com";
    var pass = "somepassword";

    //setting up SMTP client
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
    client.EnableSsl = false;

    //Create Email
    var mail = new MailMessage(from, message.Destination);
    mail.Subject = message.Subject;
    mail.Body = message.Body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    //Send email
    return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

My project builds as it does in the tutorial however, he is able to receive an email in the tutorial but I do not. I double and triple checked my username and password. What did I miss?

Comment: Enable ssl and see if it works

Comment: @Nkosi I did have it enabled. It also did not work

Comment: @Nkosi I am not getting ANY error. This is not a duplicate

Comment: what's your antivirus?  or is the port not open in a firewall?

Comment: Not that I am aware of I have webform apps that send mail all the time. I am not sure what is causing this. Should there be something in the webconfig that he is not showing?