# Why does my user return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447134/why-am-i-not-getting-a-password-reset-email) on friday because I could not figure out why my email was not getting sent out. Today in an attempt to dig a bit deeper, I set up some break points in my `forgotpassword` method. I found that the `user` variable is returning null, but I am not quite sure why?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        // Send an email with this link
        string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

The site does store email addresses in the database. I also looked to make sure that one I was putting in the model was also one used by a user and it still returned null. The one thing that is different about sign on in this application is that I changed the login page to use Username instead of email.

Comment: Because `UserManager.FindByNameAsync()` is returning null for whatever value is in `model.Email`. If you don't want to use email, don't reference the Email property...

Comment: But should it not find the email associated with the user? Even if I changed it to Username it still returns null..

Comment: Obviously the user isn't found when searching by name with their email.  Look at the users/login info table in the database.  Look at what's stored in Name.  Look at what's in the Email property.  Do they match?  Nope.  This isn't magic, it can't figure out your intent automatically.

Comment: Remember that `FindByNameAsync` is finding the user *by name*, so if your database has different usernames to email addresses, it's not going to find anything.

Comment: Well, you could use [`FindByEmailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151641(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByEmailAsync(System.String)) instead.

Comment: @DavidG I changed the email to use username should it not have find the user by name? it still returns false.

Comment: I am trying that now

Comment: @DavidG It gives me a No IUserTokenProvider is registered.

Comment: @Skullomania: That's a whole separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no material online on how to create a password token with UserManager. For anyone having this issue in the future this is how it is resolved.

**1.)** Create a new folder called MyClasses and create and add the following class

```
public class GmailEmailService:SmtpClient
{
    // Gmail user-name
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public GmailEmailService() :
        base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailHost"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailPort"]))
    {
        //Get values from web.config file:
        this.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailUserName"];
        this.EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailSsl"]);
        this.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        this.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.UserName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailPassword"]);
    }
}
```

**2.)** Configure your Identity Class

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("youremailadress@domain.com", "(any subject here)"),
    new MailAddress(message.Destination));
    email.Subject = message.Subject;
    email.Body = message.Body;

    email.IsBodyHtml = true;

    GmailEmailService mailClient = new GmailEmailService();
    await mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
}
```

**3.)** Add your credentials to the web.config. I did not use gmail in this portion because the use of gmail is blocked in my workplace and it still works perfectly.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="GmailUserName" value="youremail@yourdomain.com"/>
    <add key="GmailPassword" value="yourPassword"/>
    <add key="GmailHost" value="yourServer"/>
    <add key="GmailPort" value="yourPort"/>
    <add key="GmailSsl" value="chooseTrueOrFalse"/>
    <!--Smptp Server (confirmations emails)-->
</appSettings>
```

**4.)** Make necessary changes to your Account Controller. Add the following highlighted code.

[image: First do this]

[image: Then This]

Compile then run. Cheers!